Getting an error: 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)' on my react +flask app
Currently testing my react + flask app locally. Im hosting on EC2 but thats for prod. At first, I received an error on my web console about CORS so I temporarily disbaled it using a chrome extension. Now I receive this error:
403 error
Here is my App.js (React):
App.js
Here is my app.py (flask app):
App.py
Everything is correctly installed on my flask app using a venv. Ive got both flask and react app running at the same time. Im using .env. files for production url and dev url.
Also, when I typed in the actual localhost on axios.get() in my app.js, everything worked, I could see the json message from flask route. I have tried playing around with the code a lot from making sure everything was installed on flask, changing url on axios.get().

Be sure to place .env file in your projects frontend route folder, not src.
Check .env for typos (in your case it should look like this  REACT_APP_API_URL=http://(localhost of the backend))
Also if you are using Vite (which you should do) instead of process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL use import.meta.env.REACT_APP_API_URL
I've tested your code on my machine and everything worked
fine

The problem is not in create-react-app, you prly just made an error when creating/editing .env file. But yes, everything worked, i get 'Hi from flask' displayed and everything.
In future consider using vite for everything (even though in this case, it didnt affect the problem)

oh, i used npx create react-app, i know its no longer being supported/maintained but I just followed steps given to me by some genAI. So this worked on your machine with vite instead of create-react-app? also. I created two .env files, one for dev and another for prod so I don't have to go changing the URL whenever I want to work on dev or prod. Do you think thats fine? my .env files are in my frontend route directory, not in src or anywhere else

2 .env files should be fine if they are separated (one should be in frontend route folder other one in backend simply for safety reasons)

I think you should handle multiple .envs diferentely than 1 (using env-cmd) so try keeping 1 env file in frontend route directory

ive seperated the two .env files (dev in frontend and prod in backend). I've renamed '.env.development' to just '.env'. I have also deleted the '.env.production' file and Still getting the same 403 error status and another axios error which is stating the same thing.

Can you send more screenshots? Like route folder, and .env file. You can hide sensitive info if there is any, but i dont really get why you still getting the error

Ok, i found the issue. the url for the local host in my .env file was wrong. thanks for your help.

No problem! Use vite, and be carefull with EC2 those can get expensive

I was gonna ask if you think it wise and worth the "hassle" to switch to vite now that I got everything set up. Ive used vite before and it is pretty sweet. And yea Im gonna set up and cloud watch metric or whatever its called to send me an alert after X amount of money spent, thanks.

Depends on what you are planning to create
Vite is a life saver for big projects, it makes things work faster on dev server basically.
If you are planing to code some huge app with big size, then prly yes, because at certain point development will go slower. Create react app builts entire app before serving it in dev mode, while vite takes different and faster approach
If you are just coding something small, then continue with create react app, but use vite for all in future, its just better
